# About piecewise function without the heaviside step function .

Tags: examples-counterexamples, piecewise-continuity

Can a piecewise function of a single variable without indefinite limit can be always concentrate into a single variable function (without the heaviside step function)? Well I take an example :

Let $0.5<x\leq 1$ then define :

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$

Let $x\geq 1$ then define :

$$g(x)=x$$

Now we can concentrate the functions $f(x),g(x)$ into a new function I call $h(x)$ wich is ($x\in[0.5,\infty)$):

$$h(x)=0.5\left(x+\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}-4}\right)$$

I take a simple case but my intuition says that it's not always possible even if I haven't a counter-example .

Question :

Is it legitimate to think that my question above is necessarly false ?

Thanks !!

Comment: I we know how to do this with the Heaviside function, then we can do it using the following expression in place of the Heaviside function: $(1/2)(\sqrt{x^2}/x+1)$;

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for the reply do you want to make an answer or is it fine like this ?

Comment: Note that this trick does not work if the function is defined at the jump discontinuity. Anything you can put together with elementary functions and operations is either going to be continuous or undefined at any point. Defined but discontinuous is not an option from that operation set.